# Jenkins Blue Ocean NodeJS setup

Tags: node.js, jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

How do i setup a node.js project in Jenkins Blue Ocean? 
I keep getting a "command not found"
I installed a NodeJS version. [image: nodejs installation]

For the Pipeline settings i set
Agent - any
[image: pipeline settings]

For Init / Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH i set

NodeJSInstallationName* - nw

ConfigId - none

Child steps - Print Message
[image: Node folder]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by installing NodeJS on local machine.